# protect S3 with a firewall

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to restrict access to S3 using a firewall? We are using Palo Alto virtual firewalls in AWS. But how can we use the palo altos to protect our S3 buckets that we create?

Comment: What is your goal, AWS is doing the job for you

Comment: when we create s3 buckets, we can access them from an external source not related to the company. Like we can list and mount buckets on servers from aws accounts the company doesn't own.  We want to lock s3 buckets down with a firewall. Is this possible?

Comment: You need credentials to access to bucket it is not an open bar

Comment: Internet facing endpoint should be locked down by default; understand that access key is needed to access but it should be treated the same way as instances not accessible from internet facing  endpoint.

Comment: This is a situation that we're trying to avoid: http://gizmodo.com/top-defense-contractor-left-sensitive-pentagon-files-on-1795669632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible since S3 is a regional service which operates outside VPC . For access control you need to depend on IAM permissions and S3 access control mechanism.